# in vim command line mode: how to kill the line from the current cursor position to the end

Tags: bash, vim

the `<c-k>: kill-line` feature of bash, which means kill the line from the current cursor position to the end of the line. how to do this in `vim` command-line mode when editing the command?

for example:
when typing `:echo 'hell|o world'` this command in `vim` **command line mode** and the cursor is in `|` position, how to kill the line to become `:echo 'hell`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [this key binding in Shougo's vimrc](https://github.com/Shougo/shougo-s-github/blob/master/vim/rc/mappings.rc.vim#L57) that sets up <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> to delete until the end of the line:

```
" <C-k>, K: delete to end.
cnoremap <C-k> <C-\>e getcmdpos() == 1 ?
      \ '' : getcmdline()[:getcmdpos()-2]<CR>
```

Note that this doesn't preserve the rest of the line in a register, the way the equivalent binding in bash or Emacs does.

Check `:h eval` for more help on what you can do on the command line.

Answer (score -1):

Editing the command-line is not supposed to happen in the command-line itself but in an editor.

That's why you have `<C-x>e` in bash and `<C-f>` in Vim.

Comment: It's useful to know about those bindings; but saying you're "not supposed to" do it any other way is pretty subjective and opinion-based.